# Dynamic from(URI) in Camel

Tags: twitter, dynamic, apache-camel, consumer

I would like to create the from(URI) at runtime. I am using the twitter-component to fetch the tweets of the timeline of a user. The username of the user i would like to get from the body of the incoming message.

```
from("direct:twitterinternal")   // body contains username as string
    .from("twitter://timeline/user?type=direct&user=" + "${body}")
```

Does camel offer the possibility to create URIs at runtime?

Comment: same question with solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368961/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-from

Answer (score 2):

I generally use the [recipientList](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) pattern and the [simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) expression language for dynamic producer routes...

```
from("direct:twitterinternal")
    .recipientList(simple("twitter://timeline/user?type=direct&user=" + "${body}"))
```

otherwise, for dynamic consuming, you have 2 options:

- use a [polling consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) to dynamically build the URI to poll from
- or [add routes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451444/add-camel-route-at-runtime-in-java)

Comment: thanks for the answer!! when i use the recipientList as you explained, the twitter component acts as a producer and posts the body as tweet on the own timeline.

Comment: yep, this is for producing...if you want a consumer that uses a message to trigger it, then you'll need to use the content enricher

Comment: in the [documentation of the Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) i found the following statement: 
_pollEnrich does not access any data from the current Exchange which means when polling it cannot use any of the existing headers you may have set on the Exchange. For example you cannot set a filename in the Exchange.FILE_NAME header and use pollEnrich to consume only that file. For that you must set the filename in the endpoint URI._ As i far as i understand it, dynamic uris are not supported (because they are generated when the code is compiled). Am i correct?

Comment: the enrich() API can use data from the exchange...but not for dynamic URIs (not yet anyways, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4596)...I think you are stuck with a polling consumer (http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) and building the URI dynamically there...

Comment: otherwise, you can always add/remove routes at runtime programmatically based on user input, etc...

Answer (score -1):

Camel 2.16 or higher? Try `toD`.

http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html

Comment: Isn't that for consumer?