# call a consumer inside java(routeBuilder) from Spring dsl in camel EIP

Tags: apache-camel

[picturised..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybUFb.jpg)    I know that it is possible to call routes from from different RouteContext xml,

```
How do I achieve it in hybrid manner, for an instance..

        <route id=A>
        <from uri="direct:A"/>
        <to uri="bean:someprocess....."/>
        <to uri="direct:endp_inside_routeBuilder"/>

        <route id=B>
        <from uri="direct:A"/>
        <to uri="bean:routeBuilder?method=routeBuilderMethod"/>
        <to uri="mock:endp"/>
```

is it possible to route to the consumer inside the bean...!

or is it possible to import the routeContext/route configured in Spring into the JavaDSL ?..

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are trying to ask.  Yes You can write a route in either JavaDSL or XML.  You can also create new routes at runtime and add them to a context.  I do not understand what you mean by "route to the consumer inside the bean" or a "Hybrid manner".  If you mean you want to have a Spring DSL route call a JavaDSL route they are the same thing at runtime.  you could simply have one route send: to("direct:otherRoute")  and another route read: from("direct:otherRoute")

Comment: not possible to call the "direct" component , since its synchronous, where as I don't want to use the seda/vm, which will hamper the transaction..!

Comment: Your question is still quite unclear.  You want to maintain a transaction over a route that is asynchronous?  In order to do something like that you need to a have a single transactional flow.  You could push your message to something like ActiveMQ and then read from ActiveMQ from a different route.  This will support transactions over each individual message

Comment: let me try the messaging components and update.. :)

Comment: for ActiveMQ you will either need to run that product in standalone or an embedded mode.

Comment: sorry Matthew, its not working.., have you got a chance to try with direct component?

Comment: Would you be able to update your question with a sample use case? It looks like you're trying to parallelize a transaction's work over two routes or so.  Can you break it down a bit cleaner?

Comment: Matthew, I have embedded a picture, take a look into it..

Comment: Based on your picture it looks like all you need to know how to do is add a route to a context am I correct?  If so here is an existing post that shows how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451444/add-camel-route-at-runtime-in-java

Comment: This works, but only for a single request, if we request again to the consumer, it will throw, Failed to start route route2 because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: Endpoint[direct://newEndp], in this case, one more problem, is every time the request is made, it will create new Endpoint for the producer. Which can be an huge impact for performance, if bulk of requests arrives..

Comment: Yes You can't fire up multiple consumers from a direct endpoint.  You could switch it to a seda endpoint if that was the desired behavior.  Yes the endpoint creation can be expensive.  Are you just trying to have part of a route be parallel processing?

Comment: is there any way to initialize an endpoint only once, for each request, it should not create individual endpoints..

Comment: By default every route is only initialized once.  If you want a single execution path you can leverage a Queue based pattern and then support transactions from the queue as well as support parallelism

Comment: if you try to use toD, for each request, the endpoint is created the request number of times.

Comment: You can use a direct with multiple consumers if you use a queue.  You can use activemq, rabbitmq, webspheremq, any kind of queue platform.  I recommend activemq for this case since you can embed it into a service mix container with your came route and just use a vm transport.  This will let you still maintain transactions from the queue and have parallelism