# Apache Camel how to add/remove endpoints dynamically from a route

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration

I am trying to get familiar with EIP and Apache Camel and I have a use case that I am not quite sure how can be expressed or implemented using Camel

**Use case:**

Imagine you have designed an integration solution that takes files from an ftp, does some processing and uploads it to a queue. You chose Apache Camel to implement this solution and your route in Java DSL looks something like this:

```
 from("ftp://user@hostname/directoryname")
   .process(new Processor() {
              public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
              {
                //my fantastic prosessing goes here
              }
 }).to("jms:queue:queueName");
```

the route could be way more complex than this, but it doesn't matter here. Imagine your solution is such a spectacular success that there's a plan to implement a service where anyone could add his ftp server and get the files processed and uploaded to the queue. So what you want is

1. (Flexibility) Being able to dynamically add/remove servers from your app
2. (Scaling) Being able to handle potentially large number of such servers

Let's forget about #2 and focus on Flexibility part.

So the question is, I suppose:

**How to dynamically (at runtime) add/remove endpoints to/from Apache Camel route?**

**What I considered so far:**

First, I admit I am not that familiar with Integration Patterns, but just scanning the catalogue, the only thing that kind of could fit the bill is the *Content Enricher*. It can take a message and just go off to somewhere else and bring sth else. So I was thinking if someone adds an ftp server, the connection details could be encapsulated in the message and a *Content Enricher* could then connect to that ftp server and fetch files and push it further through the route.... so it would effectively be a *Content Enricher* capable of  connecting to multiple ftp servers.... That kind of sound wrong. First I don't think this is the intention behind that pattern and secondly since there's ftp *Component* in Camel, I should somehow be able to use it in that scenario

The second approach would be to break the route into two like using the *vm* component, like this:

```
 from("ftp://user@hostname/directoryname").to("vm:internalQ");
 from("vm:internalQ")
   .process(new Processor() {
              public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
              {
                //my fantastic prosessing goes here
              }
 }).to("jms:queue:queueName");
```

so now, I can create many routes with ftp endpoints that write to that internal queue so it can be picked up. Adding route dynamically to *CamelContext* seems to be possible ([Add camel route at runtime in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451444/add-camel-route-at-runtime-in-java)). Is that the way to go? Or am I just trying to use *Camel* in a way that it was not designed to?

Comment: I dont think I got the question correctly. You can have as many camel routes to read from ftp as u want. You can use headers - CamelFileName, CamelFileHost, CamelFileLocalWorkPath to route files using same route..

Comment: Can you add the routes and remove them dynamically without interrupting anything else in the context? It's the dynamic part I am not sure about

Comment: I guess I fixed myself on the idea of dynmaically adding endpoints to the route, but perhaps, it's the routes that should be dynamically added... which kind of make sense.... I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically add routes to your `CamelContext`:

```
MyRouteBuilder trb = new MyRouteBuilder(servletEndpoint, mockEndpoint);
camelContext.addRoutes(trb);
```

And MyRouteBuilder:

```
MyRouteBuilder(Endpoint servletEndpointStart, MockEndpoint mockEndpointEnd, String allowedParameters){
        this._servletEndpoint = servletEndpointStart;
        this._mockEndpoint = mockEndpointEnd;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(this._servletEndpoint)
        .id(TESTING_ROUTE_NAME)
        .process(new Processor(){ // some processor })
        .to(_mockEndpoint);
    }
```

You can also modify the route, but you will need to restart it, in order to work properly, checkout how it is done in:
`org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.adviceWith(ModelCamelContext, RouteBuilder)`

Comment: I am accepting the answer, though I am still not certain this is the best way of approaching this particular use case. Thanks